# Couldn't get the right coffee color and the thickness of glass cup

Tags: glass

I was trying to follow the coffee cup tutorial by Blender Guru on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdWUjEMzDhg&t=235s
However, I have two major problems with my own project:
1， I couldn't get the right coffee color changing the "Color" and "Density" in Materials -> Volume (Volume absorption), I've also tried changing Base color in Principled BSDF but I got nothing close to real coffee color. Both colors don't work the way I thought.
2, There's no gap between liquid and the cup outer wall (no thinkness of the glass cup).
[image]

Comment: Blender file attached[link]https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11vxhEN6v368mkW5bhWUFZB5ix18kMqVt?usp=sharing

Comment: The glass is supposed to work this way with the Principled, if you don't want this kind of glass you should use a mix of nodes like Glass, Transparent and Glossy. Your coffee seems ok as well

Comment: I would try to use mix nodes to give some thickness to the wall, but the color still look a bit off from my own perspective. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I will give a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given a try for the glass material, it's not completely accurate but in my opinion it creates the illusion. I haven't changed the coffee material itself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great contribution! By looking at the picture, the color of coffee looks much better and the thickness of the glass is indeed expressed. I will try out in the weekend (will update)